# JPA JAX-RS JSF cross communication

Tags: jpa, jax-rs, jsf-2.2

I am new to Java Technology Stack, I am wondering if it is possible to have JPA stand alone project deployed as war/jar managed by container, and also another war using JAX-RS on same container to communicate with the jpa project, possible another project jsf also communicate with jpa or jax-rs project is possible to do that? And how would I approach it? What if each project is living on different containers residing on same network?

I really appreciate your feedback

Thanks

Comment: This construct is called EAR. One JAR and two or more WARs together in EAR. The "different containers" part is ambiguous. If it are really physically standalone servers (not a cluster), then just include JAR in each WAR.

Comment: How do I implement EAR application, can u provide me with some real world scenarios. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the `ejb-in-ear` quickstart in the [Wildfly Quickstart](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/) GitHub repository.

It will make a project that contains three projects, one the ear project, one the ejb project, and one the web project.

The ear project deploys everything to you application server.

The ejb project has your JPA stuff in it.

The web project has your JSF stuff in it.

Works great, always easiest to start learning by example. However, if you are just learning Java EE technology, you should probably start with one of the simpler quickstarts. I like the kitchensink quickstart.